# What is the difference between "Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]" and "[a] -> [a] -> [a]"

Tags: list, haskell

I am new in Haskell. Can anyone explain the difference and the usage of `Ord a`?

Now I'm familiar with `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` things. But this,

```
Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

please explain me in detail.

Comment: You restrict `a` to be a member of the `Ord` typeclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
-- merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]  ?
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | y < x     = y : merge (x:xs) ys
  | otherwise = x : merge xs (y:ys)
```

In particular, look at the second-to-last line. See that `(<)` operator?

```
ghci> :i (<)
class Eq a => Ord a where
  ...
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

We can see here that the less-than operator does not exist for type not of class `Ord`; that `merge` function therefore makes no sense unless we have `Ord a`. We therefore rewrite its type signature as:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the constraint, `Ord a => a` here `a` has type `a` but not any `a`, an `a` that is an instance of `Ord` typeclass, example:

here I will change a little bit the type result only to show you can use the functions of the interface:

```
canBeOrderedList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
canBeOrderedList xs ys = zipWith (>) xs ys
```

here you can do whatever generic function you want, `a` here is not restricted, so it can be `Ord` or `Eq` or both or none, can be functions, can be Ints can be anything

```
anyListTypeConcat :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
anyListTypeConcat xs ys  = xs ++ ys
```

so:

```
anyListTypeConcat [True, False] [False, True]
=> [True,False,False,True]
```

here you concatted the two list, so far so good, here:

```
canBeOrderedList [1,2,3] [4,1,2]
=> [False,True,True]
```

you can use (>) with numbers but, what about:

```
data Some = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show)

anyListTypeConcat [A, A] [B, C]
=> [A,A,B,C]
```

but:

```
canBeOrderedList [A,A,B] [C,A,A]
 error:
    • No instance for (Ord Some)
        arising from a use of ‘canBeOrderedList’
    • In the expression: canBeOrderedList [A, A, B] [C, A, A]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = canBeOrderedList [A, A, B] [C, A, A]
```

You cannot order that list, but you may if you change the data type:

```
data Some = A | B | C deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
canBeOrderedList [A,A,B] [C,A,A]
=> [False,False,True]
```

And that's essentially the difference